# Hide list numbering when a list's id is hidden

Tags: javascript, html

I want the list numbers to be hidden along with the text inside it.

Current Output:

```
1.Two

2.Three
```

Desired Output:

```
2.Two 

3.Three
```

Code:

```js
var element = document.getElementById("one");
element.style.display = 'none';
```

```html
<ol>
  <li id="one">
    One
  </li>
  <li id="two">
    Two
  </li>
  <li id="three">
    Three
  </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Did you really want the `One` element in the desired output?

Comment: No, I meant to leave that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var element = document.getElementById("one");
element.style.display = 'none';


// we get the children to find the actual position of our element.
var list = [].slice.call(element.parentNode.children); 
// we get the current position
var curPos = list.indexOf(element);

// we set the next element to start the count from the removed one
// we don't forget that is zero based index !
list[curPos + 1].value = curPos+2;
```

```html
<ol>
  <li id="one">
    One
  </li>
  <li id="two">
    Two
  </li>
  <li id="three">
    Three
  </li>
  <li id="four">
    Four
  </li>
  <li id="five">
    Five
  </li>
  
</ol>
```